# Confirm X server is working

Tags: xubuntu, xorg

I am trying to install Oracle on my Ubuntu.  This is NOT an oracle question, but when I run the runInstaller it runs through so environment checks.  I pass all but one,  the display check.  it runs:

```
/usr/bin/xdpyinfo
```

when I run that, I get:

```
/usr/bin/xdpyinfo:  unable to open display "127.0.0.1:0:0".
```

I did run (as root)

```
xhost +127.0.0.1
```

I how does one go about fixing this?

-------  UPDATE

I removed my manual setting of $DISPLAY.

so if I start a terminal session as myself,  (ie  ctrl+alt+t)  and run "xterm"  I get a new terminal.  Also,  when i echo $DISPLAY I get :0

when I su to my oracle user,  and run "xterm" I get: 
     xterm
     No protocol specified
     xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :0

Does that help anyone?  why can't my oracle user use xterm?

Any the installer works fine under my own account.  So something about how I created the oracle user won't let me run xterm

Comment: Whats the output of `echo "$DISPLAY"` ?

Comment: echo $DISPLAY give me:  127.0.0.1:0:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you see are symptomatic of a missing X authorization file. I've has a similar problem running any GUI application as root in Ubuntu 15.04, and I discovered that it was because Ubuntu was giving the root user an invalid environment variable.

So: from your Oracle user, see if "echo $XAUTHORITY" gives you a path that actually exists. If not, copy .Xauthority from your login directory to your Oracle user, issue "export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority", and try creating your xterm again.

I realize this should be posted as a comment, but I don't have the requisite 50 reputation to do so. It's unfortunate that I have to break the rules to get this information to you.

Comment: Should not be a comment as it is the correct answer!  I did have an .Xauthourity file in my oracle user home, but that clearly was not working.  I copied my personal .Xauthority file over..  and presto!